# Infinite While Loop in C#, CPU usage 100%

Tags: c#, while-loop, cpu-usage

I have a web response stream which produces data intermittently. There is no way of knowing when will data be received on this channel.

In order to read all data in my application, I use a while(true) which results in 100% CPU usage.

I cannot use ManualResetEvent as the application has to keep reading from the stream all the time. This works OK as long as data is received but when there is no data in stream, other threads cannot get enough CPU time to process.
My code looks like:-

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
while(true)
{
    int charvalue = streamReader.Read();
    // More code to process data read above
}
```

I don't want to use Thread.Sleep() as it slows my application unnecessarily and still want other threads to process when there is no data received on this thread.

Comment: Won't it block on `Read`?

Comment: You need to have some condition other than `while(true)`, otherwise it will continue forever. I'm guessing you do not have a `break` inside your loop either?

Comment: well thread.Sleep() is the answer, it will only sleep your current thread, and yes if you have no data to read, just sleep some time and then recheck again

Comment: if (charvalue == -1) break;

Comment: `Read()` should block until next character is available, unless end of stream is reached, in which case it indeed will return `-1` without blocking. But if stream has ended, it cannot be "resumed" anyway, so just check for `-1` and break the loop.

Comment: "I don't want to use Thread.Sleep() as it slows my application unnecessarily" -- so does a CPU core pegged at 100%. Sleeping for 1ms will give you your core back, as 1ms is a lifetime to a CPU. "and still want other threads to process when there is no data received on this thread." -- that makes no sense. You're burning a thread in this loop continually, regardless of whether `Read` blocks or not. The thread doing this work will literally never do anything else.

Comment: @PatrickHofman & Evk :- Yes it does blocks at read but apparently the CPU is still being used by this thread. Because when there is no data received at the stream (& it is not end of stream), other threads still don't get enough CPU time.

Comment: I really doubt that @pull420

Comment: @all to give you guys more context about the application, this thread would put everything received in a queue and other thread(s) is responsible for parsing and processing that data.

Comment: @pull420 do a google search on how to read a a stream in a while loop, you could have solved your problem by now

Comment: Then use Aync event : request.BeginGetResponse()

Comment: So, do you break when `charvalue` is -1 or not, after all?

Comment: @Evk :- yes I do break at the end of stream i.e. when char value is -1. But these connections are supposed to run indefinitely unless the server breaks them or they are broken due to network connections. These are supposed to be persistent connections retrieving data indefinitely in best case scenario.

Comment: I understand, but still I cannot believe `Read` will return without blocking in any condition except end of stream reached (and if connection is broken - that is also end of stream). So your while loop should not consume CPU when no data is available and stream is not finished - it will just sleep blocked on Read. Either confirm that with debugger, or try to search some another place which can consume your CPU.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for everyone's responses. Finally I tried by profiling the windows service and found that the bottleneck was a string manipulation that I was doing inside this while loop and not the loop itself. As mentioned by @Evk "Read" was working as expected i.e. blocking the current thread when there was no data in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

make an async method and do it with await Task.Delay()

```
public async void ReadFromStream(StreamReader streamReader)
{
 while(true)
 {
    int charvalue = streamReader.Read();
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    // add this data to some list, queue or something else so you could use it somewhere else easily and then just use this data in your other methods

 }
}
```

then just call it, it will run indefinely in the background. Make it pass your results to some queue and then you will be free to use those results as you please, dequeue the data to a list and do whatever you want with them.